# how can i control shockwaveflash object BGColor with colordialogue in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have the following code

```
Private Sub select_color_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles select_color.Click
        Dim ocolor As New ColorDialog
        ocolor.ShowDialog()


        Me.BackColor = ocolor.Color

    End Sub
```

and it changes the background color of form to the color i select in colordialogue...

now i want to change the BGColor of shockwaveobject in this way...however i can change the BGColor of shockwave object manually in toolbox but i want to change it by color dialogue how can i do that...

Comment: What is "shockwaveobject"? Could you provide a link to its documentation?

Comment: it is a flash component to play flash movies in vb.net...you can get it by right clicking on your tool box and select choose items and from COM tab select Shockwave Object and hit ok than drag an instance to form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the color to a string:

```
    Dim ocolor As New ColorDialog
    If ocolor.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.SwfObject.BGColor = ocolor.Color.R.ToString("X2") & ocolor.Color.G.ToString("X2") & ocolor.Color.B.ToString("X2")
    End If
```